# How to change the notification sound of the iPhone using one coming from the iPod library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, notifications

I have an alarm app in which I have a tableview where I am accessing all the iPod library songs. I want that when any of this song is selected this song must be set to the notification sound so when the alarm appears the alarm should ring with the sound selected from the iPod library.

Comment: what do you mean by **set to the notification sound**?? What is exact problem you are facing??

Comment: @DShah actually i have a tableview where in third row when i click i am able to access my ipod library .Now my problem when i select any of the song from the ipod library that song should get set to the notification sound i.e when the alarm rings the notification should  ring with that song

Answer (score 0):

ok I got your point. In my similar case i have achieved in following way, but that was somewhat different case. You can try one of the following case.

**ONE CASE:**

You can do one thing is You can store the `URL` of iPod Library song in `NSUserDefault` and pass that URL in `didReceivedNotification` method to your MPMediaPlayer class.

**SECOND CASE**

Another case will be copying the selected song in your app's document folder and then use that song for playing. For this you need to take care of previous files and delete them when selected new. This could make your app size somewhat larger.

Comment: Actually i am getting totally confused on how to do this.Can u please help me on this .Do u have any sample code.Then please help me.Thanks

Comment: but i think we cant play a sound which is more than 30 sec

Comment: Why do you say so?? It should depends on what Library are you using...  if you use AudioService then it has restriction... but if you are using AVAudioPlayer... then you can play for long time...